# Two axes in matplotlib histogram for the two issues of the target

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to plot a histogram of the distribution of the features of a dataframe but I don't know how to put two axes to bypass the repartition of my target.

For instance, this is what I had :

```
def show_distrib(dataset,rows,cols):
    x1 = dataset[dataset['embauche']==0]
    x2 = dataset[dataset['embauche']==1]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    for i,feature in enumerate(dataset.columns):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(rows,cols,i+1)
        print(feature)
        ax.hist([x1[feature],x2[feature]],label=['non','oui'],bins=10,color=['r','b'])
        ax.legend(loc = 'upper left')
        ax.set_title('Distribution de '+str(feature))
    plt.show()
show_distrib(dataset.dropna(),4,4)
```

[image]
So the xlabel are there as I want but the thing is I would like to have two axes for my histograms not to take into account the relative repartition of 'oui' and 'non'

So this is what I tried to do so:

```
def show_distrib(df,cols):
    emb = df[df.embauche==1]
    n_emb = df[df.embauche==0]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))
    for i,col in enumerate(cols):
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(7, 2, i+1)
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        n, bins, patches = ax1.hist([emb[col],n_emb[col]], bins=20, color=['b','r'])
        ax1.cla()
        width = (bins[1]-bins[0])*0.4
        bins_shifted = bins + width
        ax1.bar(bins[:-1], n[0], width, color = 'b')
        ax2.bar(bins_shifted[:-1], n[1], width, color='r')
        ax1.set_ylabel('oui', color='b')
        ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')
        ax2.set_ylabel('non', color='r')
        ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')
        ax1.set_title('Distribution de {}'.format(col))
    plt.show()
show_distrib(dataset.dropna(),dataset.drop(['embauche'],axis=1).columns)
```

[image]
But now my xlabel have been changed into quantitative because of the conversion from hist to bar and I don't know how to retrieve them.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you mean by relative repartition?

Comment: I don’t want to compare the two labels by the time of occurrence but by their ratio percentage